# Why "Skip" and "Take" is taking longer time when the record being fetched is getting more and more?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

There is more than `50,000 records` in the table. I am using `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR)`.

I have used the code to fetch 200 records at a time. The below code seems to work fine till 1000 records but after that it starts taking longer time.

**Code**

```
int skip = 0; //Initially and gets increased by 200 for each calls (0, 200, 400, so on)
int take = 200; //Initially and remains same since only 200 records needed at a time.

var recordList = context.Records.OrderBy(x => x.IncentiveOUID)
                                .Skip(skip)
                                .Take(take)
                                .ToList();
```

**Generated SQL Code**

```
SELECT TOP (200)
   [Extent1].[IncentiveOUID] AS [IncentiveOUID],
   [Extent1].[IncentiveID] AS [IncentiveID],
   [Extent1].[OrganizationUnitID] AS [OrganizationUnitID],
   [Extent1].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate],
   [Extent1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy],
   [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
   FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[IncentiveOUID] AS [IncentiveOUID], [Extent1].[IncentiveID] 
   AS [IncentiveID], [Extent1].[OrganizationUnitID] 
   AS [OrganizationUnitID], [Extent1].[ModifiedDate] 
   AS [ModifiedDate], [Extent1].[ModifiedBy] 
   AS [ModifiedBy], [Extent1].[Id] 
   AS [Id], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[IncentiveOUID] ASC) AS [row_number]
       FROM [dbo].[cms_IncentiveOUs] AS [Extent1]
   )  AS [Extent1]
   WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 2400
   ORDER BY [Extent1].[IncentiveOUID] ASC
```

Ready to provide more information if needed to explain the above stuffs.

Comment: It would be nice to have the whole function or at least where `skip` is being increased and how `recordList` is being used after populating it.

Comment: @ikerbera `skip` is coming from the client side and it's coming properly to the method and there is nothing I am doing with the `recordList`, it is simply returned from the method.

Comment: What database is this, id be interested in the generated sql too.

Comment: That is happening because more records are skipped which should take longer time.How about loading all the records to a data table?

Comment: @preciousbetine Can you please provide the sample code for the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL has no efficient way to `Skip`: it must read all preceding rows. You're performing a scan on the index every time you fetch a page of records, with every page scanning more and more of the index.

Instead of paginating results, consider fetching them at offsets. Something like:

```
IEnumerable<Record> GetNext(int fromId = 0, int take = 50) => context.Records
    .Where(x => x.Id > fromId)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Take(take)
    .ToList();
```

Which with an index on `Id` will translate into a maximally efficient index seek.

Comment: @This solved my issue. The problem was with the `ng-repeat with filter in angularjs` which was slowing down the performance.